# Converting array to string implementing "and" only onto the last index

Tags: data-conversion

looked through the forum and only found the basics to converting arrays into strings. I'm looking to convert the array with commas and adds a final "and" to the last number

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

=> array= "1, 2, 3, and 4"
```

Comment: which programming language are you using here?

Comment: Using ruby language